# How to have dynamic Box<dyn Trait<T,S>>?

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch

I have a list of transactions of type `T` and `S`. At run time I want to fetch its details.
How to have traits for multiple generics types for struct
Code? I tried the following code:

```
    use std::fmt::Debug;
    use std::any::Any;
    
    
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct TransactionSet<T,S> {
        pub name: String,
        pub key: T,
        pub value: S
    }
    
    trait Details<T,S> {
        fn get_details(&self);
    
        fn get_key(&self)->&T;
    
        fn get_value(&self)->&S;
    }
    
    impl<T: Debug, S: Debug> Details<T,S> for TransactionSet<T, S> {
        fn get_details(&self) {
            println!("{:?} {:?} {:?}",self.name.to_string(),&self.key,&self.value)
        }

        fn get_key(&self)->&T {
            &self.key
        }
    
        fn get_value(&self)->&S {
            &self.value
        }
    
    }
    
        
    fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
        println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
    }
    
    fn get<T: Any>(value: Box<dyn Any>) -> T {
        let pv = value.downcast().expect("The pointed-to value must be of type T");
        *pv
    }
    
       
    fn main() {
        //let mut vec: Vec<Box<dyn NewTrait<T:Debug,S:Debug>>> = Vec::new(); //Not working
        //  let mut vec: Vec<Box<dyn Details<T: Debug,S: Debug>>> = Vec::new();//Cannot use Details Trait
        let  vec: Vec<Box<dyn Details<_,_>>> = Vec::new();//Cannot use Details Trait
    
        let a1:TransactionSet<String,String> = TransactionSet { name: String::from("Test1"), key: String::from("name"), value: String::from("vinay") };
        let a2:TransactionSet<String,i32> = TransactionSet { name: String::from("Test2"), key: String::from("age"), value: 32_i32 };
        let a3 = TransactionSet { name: String::from("Test3"), key: 1_i32, value: 10_u64 };
        let a4 = TransactionSet { name: String::from("Test4"), key: String::from("isEligibleToVote"), value: true };
    
        //let a2 = ABC::new( String::from("Test2"), String::from("company"),  String::from("supra"));;
    
        vec.push(Box::<TransactionSet<String,String>>::new(a1));
        vec.push(Box::<TransactionSet<String,i32>>::new(a2));
        vec.push(Box::new(a3));
        vec.push(Box::new(a4));
        for v in vec.iter() {
            v.get_details();
            //  print_type_of(v);
    
            println!("Key : {:?}", v.get_key());
            println!("Value : {:?}", v.get_value());
        }
    
    }
```

Is there any other way I can resolve this?
Like `Vec<Box<dyn Details<?Unknown,?Unknown>>>`. If I remove the generic type for trait `Details`, I cannot write a getter for it.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3cdf5f5f5e56cdf61947e5cb80aefd78)

Comment: That is not gonna work per se. You are trying to mix types.

Comment: @Netwave I want to have TransactionSet which can have dynamic types. How can i do it ?

Comment: That is ok, but the types would need to be boxed too.

Comment: @Netwave Can you share demo on playground

Comment: @Netwave Can you share a playground link where S is vec[S]

Comment: Vinay, `Vec<S>`  where `S` is `Debug` should work straight with the example below. If you need to modify behaviour implement `Details` for `TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Vec<Box<dyn Debug>>>`

Comment: @Netwave How do i create function to iterate vec<Box<dyn Debug>>,it says
 
`let mut vec: &Vec<Box<dyn Details<Name=String, Key=Box<dyn Debug, Global>, Value=Box<dyn Debug, Global>>, Global>, Global> =v;`
Its failing

Comment: Uhm, I cant help you without more information. Please post a playground link at least.

Comment: @Netwave I was able to do that . Thanks for all your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `dyn` in order to abstract to the trait you need.

First step is to add types to your trait, it does not need to be generic:

```
trait Details {
    type Key;
    type Value;
    fn get_details(&self);

    fn get_key(&self) -> &Self::Key;

    fn get_value(&self) -> &Self::Value;
}
```

Then you can implement the trait over some generic `TransactionSet` where both `T` and `S` implement `Debug`:

```
impl Details for TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Box<dyn Debug>> {
    type Key = Box<dyn Debug>;
    type Value = Box<dyn Debug>;
    fn get_details(&self) {
        println!(
            "{:?} {:?} {:?}",
            self.name.to_string(),
            &self.key,
            &self.value
        )
    }
    fn get_key(&self) -> &Self::Key {
        &self.key
    }

    fn get_value(&self) -> &Self::Value {
        &self.value
    }
}
```

Note that the type of your `TransactionSet` is of `TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Box<dyn Debug>>`.

Here is a full working example:

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TransactionSet<T, S> {
    pub name: String,
    pub key: T,
    pub value: S,
}

trait Details {
    type Key;
    type Value;
    fn get_details(&self);

    fn get_key(&self) -> &Self::Key;

    fn get_value(&self) -> &Self::Value;
}

impl Details for TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Box<dyn Debug>> {
    type Key = Box<dyn Debug>;
    type Value = Box<dyn Debug>;
    fn get_details(&self) {
        println!(
            "{:?} {:?} {:?}",
            self.name.to_string(),
            &self.key,
            &self.value
        )
    }
    fn get_key(&self) -> &Self::Key {
        &self.key
    }

    fn get_value(&self) -> &Self::Value {
        &self.value
    }
}

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

fn get<T: Any>(value: Box<dyn Any>) -> T {
    let pv = value
        .downcast()
        .expect("The pointed-to value must be of type T");
    *pv
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<Box<dyn Details<Key = _, Value = _>>> = Vec::new(); //Cannot use Details Trait

    let a1: TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Box<dyn Debug>> = TransactionSet {
        name: String::from("Test1"),
        key: Box::new(String::from("name")),
        value: Box::new(String::from("vinay")),
    };
    let a2: TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Box<dyn Debug>> = TransactionSet {
        name: String::from("Test2"),
        key: Box::new(String::from("age")),
        value: Box::new(32_i32),
    };
    // let a3 = TransactionSet { name: String::from("Test3"), key: 1_i32, value: 10_u64 };
    // let a4 = TransactionSet { name: String::from("Test4"), key: String::from("isEligibleToVote"), value: true };

    vec.push(Box::<TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Box<dyn Debug>>>::new(
        a1,
    ));
    vec.push(Box::<TransactionSet<Box<dyn Debug>, Box<dyn Debug>>>::new(a2));
    // vec.push(Box::new(a3));
    // vec.push(Box::new(a4));
    for v in vec.iter() {
        v.get_details();
        //  print_type_of(v);

        println!("Key : {:?}", v.get_key());
        println!("Value : {:?}", v.get_value());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d66315cadd7dfa4932237cf2560cdbf)